# MobileFirst 7.1 runtime not visible while accessing it from ihs

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server, worklight-security, mobilefirst-appcenter

we are using liberty profile and when i am trying to access `MobileFirst` console from `Appserver` it is working fine but when i am trying to access it from IHS i am able to access `mobilefirst` console but i am not able to see `mobilefirst` runtime.
[this link images show worklight console accessing through ihs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRwRq.jpg)

**access.logs of ihs**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:33:19 +0300] "GET /appcenterconsole/console.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1030
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:33:20 +0300] "GET /appcenterconsole/dojo/appcenter/templates/Main.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1509
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:33:20 +0300] "GET /appcenterconsole/services?action=endpoint HTTP/1.1" 200 66
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:33:20 +0300] "GET /appcenterconsole/dojo/appcenter/templates/ApplicationsList.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2224
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:33:20 +0300] "GET /appcenterconsole/services/service/userAndConfigInfo?request.preventCache=1485765200702 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:33:20 +0300] "GET /appcenterconsole/services/service/directory?pageSize=15&fromIndex=0&orderBy=label&isActive=any&isInstaller=any&isRecommended=any&isReadyForProd=any&isRTWAnnotated=any&isAppLink=any&request.preventCache=1485765200896 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:33:26 +0300] "GET /appcenterconsole/console.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1030
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:33:26 +0300] "GET /appcenterconsole/dojo/appcenter/templates/Main.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1509
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:33:26 +0300] "GET /appcenterconsole/services?action=endpoint HTTP/1.1" 200 66
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:33:26 +0300] "GET /appcenterconsole/dojo/appcenter/templates/ApplicationsList.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2224
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:33:26 +0300] "GET /appcenterconsole/services/service/userAndConfigInfo?request.preventCache=1485765206923 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:33:27 +0300] "GET /appcenterconsole/services/service/directory?pageSize=15&fromIndex=0&orderBy=label&isActive=any&isInstaller=any&isRecommended=any&isReadyForProd=any&isRTWAnnotated=any&isAppLink=any&request.preventCache=1485765207144 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/libs/requirejs/require.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 7390
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/index.html HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 270
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/login.html HTTP/1.1" 200 3261
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/libs/requirejs-dplugins/i18n.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1880
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/libs/mf-ui-css-foundation/dist/styles/extensions/header.css HTTP/1.1" 200 504
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1837
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/js/login/login.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1259
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/locale HTTP/1.1" 200 18
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/libs/requirejs-dplugins/i18n.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/libs/requirejs-dplugins/i18n/build.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1187
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/libs/requirejs-dplugins/i18n/common.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1036
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/libs/requirejs-dplugins/i18n/parentLocale.js HTTP/1.1" 200 429
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:07 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/js/login/nls/login.js HTTP/1.1" 200 737
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:21 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:21 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/libs/mf-ui-css-foundation/dist/styles/extensions/header.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:43 +0300] "POST /worklightconsole/j_security_check HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:43 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1640
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:43 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/css/app-layer.css HTTP/1.1" 200 6462
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:43 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 46380
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:43 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/locale HTTP/1.1" 200 18
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:43 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/js/css/layer.css HTTP/1.1" 200 7585
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:43 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/js/nls/main_root.js HTTP/1.1" 200 7225
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:43 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/libs/angular-layer.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 75558
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:43 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/services?action=endpoint HTTP/1.1" 200 59
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:44 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/services?action=userinfo HTTP/1.1" 200 85
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:43 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/services/management-apis/1.0/loginAudit HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:42:44 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/services/management-apis/1.0/runtimes?fullInfo=true HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:53:28 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1640
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:53:28 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/css/app-layer.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:53:28 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/libs/requirejs/require.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:53:28 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:53:28 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/locale HTTP/1.1" 200 18
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:53:28 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/js/css/layer.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:53:28 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/libs/angular-layer.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:53:28 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/201602212243/js/nls/main_root.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:53:28 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/services?action=endpoint HTTP/1.1" 200 59
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:53:29 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/services?action=userinfo HTTP/1.1" 200 85
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:53:28 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/services/management-apis/1.0/loginAudit HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2017:11:53:29 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/services/management-apis/1.0/runtimes?fullInfo=true HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Management API calls are resulting in Error 500:

[30/Jan/2017:11:53:28 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/services/management-apis/1.0/loginAudit HTTP/1.1" 500 - 127.0.0.1 - - 
[30/Jan/2017:11:53:29 +0300] "GET /worklightconsole/services/management-apis/1.0/runtimes?fullInfo=true HTTP/1.1" 500 -

1) Please upload your server.xml 
2) Are you accessing the console ( via IHS) from the internet ?

Comment: you can view server.xml from this link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0iSoHPRAnqiMFNtbzFYMTV0ckk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try the ibm.worklight.admin.proxy.* JNDI properties as mentioned in the link:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/r_wladmin_jndi_property_list.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not sure it might resolve it. Put your External IHS domain in the application runtime to make it accessible.

[image]